# datatemplate and binding

Tags: xaml

how can i use Binding from listBox if it get there listBoxItem from dataTemplate  to show the selected item in label

this is my code :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="data">
        <x:XData>
            <colors xmlns="">
                <color name="yellow"/>
                <color name="red"/>
                <color name="blue"/>
                <color name="black"/>
                <color name="pink"/>
                <color name="brown"/>
                </colors>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="temp">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Content="{Binding XPath=@name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>



</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

    <ListBox Name="lblColor" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource data}, XPath=colors/color}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource temp}" Background="Transparent" SelectedIndex="0"></ListBox>
    <Label Content="your choice is :"></Label>

    <Label ></Label>


</StackPanel>
```

I want to show the selected item in the content of the last label ...
thanks for any help .

Comment: use `DisplayMemberPath` or `BindingMemberPath` instead and remove the XPath=colors/color put Xpath=color instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lblColor" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource data}, XPath=colors/color}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource temp}" Background="Transparent" SelectedIndex="0" SelectedValuePath="@name" ></ListBox>
    <Label Content="your choice is :"></Label>

    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=lblColor,Path=SelectedValue}"   />
```